# How do I get the menu title via the menu name, Drupal 7 API

Tags: routes

I'd like to get the title of the menu.

if I do:

```
menu_navigation_links('menu-name');
```

I get only the links without the title, which is good but I still need the title.

Any ideas ?

Cheers

Comment: Didn't know that menus have a title field ... Is your menu part of a block ? Blocks can have titles.

Comment: well when you create a menu you give him a title, that was I was looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menu_load('menu-name');
```

Returns title, description and menu_name for this menu.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!menu!menu.module/function/menu_load/7

Comment: That was it! Cheers michamilz